# Create application on Orbeon under apps/myApp/subFolder

Tags: orbeon

I'm using Orbeon 3.7.0 beta1 under WAS 7.1.

I have an external application that place XForms (the XHTML and page-flow.xml) under `orbeon.war/WEB-INF/resources/apps/myApplication/myUser/` of Orbeon deployed project.

My problem is that Orbeon only reads `page-flow.xml` if it is placed under "apps/myApplication/" since the default behavior of Orbeon is that.

How can I reach my application if it is placed under a subfolder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic to how nested page flows are handled. The top-level page flow dispatches to sub-page flows with the following rule in the top-level page-flow.xml:

```
<page id="apps"
  path-info="/([^/]+)/.*"
  matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher"
  model="apps/${1}/page-flow.xml"/>
```

You should be able to write a similar rule but which goes one more level deeper. I haven't tried this but something like this:

```
<page id="apps2"
  path-info="/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.*"
  matcher="oxf:perl5-matcher"
  model="apps/${1}/${2}/page-flow.xml"/>
```